# Allowed names for TypeScript interfaces

Tags: typescript

Consider this code, which compiles fine:

```
interface Whatever {
    name: string;
}

var x : Whatever = {
    name: "Whatever"
};
```

Change "Whatever" to "Map" and you get this code:

```
interface Map {
    name: string;
}

var x : Map = {
    name: "Whatever"
};
```

When I compile that using `tsc` (installed from npm on the latest Ubuntu), I get this nasty looking output:

```
test.ts(1,11): error TS2234: All declarations of an interface must have identical type parameters.
test.ts(5,5): error TS2012: Cannot convert '{ name: string; }' to 'Map<any, any>':
    Type '{ name: string; }' is missing property 'clear' from type 'Map<any, any>'.
test.ts(5,9): error TS2173: Generic type references must include all type arguments.
```

I'm completely new to TypeScript, so I'm not really sure what that means. I guess that something is already named `Map` by default, maybe? Anyone know what's going on? And is there some definitive list of restrictions on what I can name my interfaces?

Comment: Side note: this was literally the first interface I ever wrote in TypeScript and I spent way too long banging my head against the wall before realizing everything would work if I just changed the name from "Map" to something else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've encountered is that there are interfaces pre-defined for a number of ECMAScript 6 features, including `Map` (an explanation is [here](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3asimple_maps_and_sets) for the `Map` specification):

```
// lib.t.ts
//
/////////////////////////////
/// IE11 ECMAScript Extensions
/////////////////////////////
interface Map<K, V> {
    clear(): void;
    delete(key: K): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, index: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    get(key: K): V;
    has(key: K): boolean;
    set(key: K, value: V): Map<K, V>;
    size: number;
}
declare var Map: {
    new <K, V>(): Map<K, V>;
}
```

So, you just happened across a type that is already defined in the global namespace. If you wanted, you could add a `module` to allow you to use an exported interface without issue.

```
module Special {
    export interface Map {
        name: string;
    }
}
```